# What is difference between @XSlf4j and @Slf4j annotation in Lombok?

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, lombok

Can someone please explain the difference between `lombok.extern.slf4j.XSlf4j` and `lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j`? Looks like `XSlf4j` is a new addition, why was this new annotation added to Lombok library.

Comment: Did you try reading the Javadoc on those annotations?

Comment: Yes, the javadoc did not explained why and when to use this @XSlf4 annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One annotation results in a normal logger, the other results in an extended logger.

Lombok generates this code for the xslf4j annotation (this code came from https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/slf4j/XSlf4j):

```
 private static final org.slf4j.ext.XLogger log = org.slf4j.ext.XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(LogExample.class);
```

XLogger is an extended logger, see https://www.slf4j.org/extensions.html, it has a description starting with this summary:

> The XLogger class provides a few extra logging methods that are quite useful for following the execution path of applications. These methods generate logging events that can be filtered separately from other debug logging. Liberal use of these methods is encouraged as the output has been found to
>
> - aid in problem diagnosis in development without requiring a debug session
> - aid in problem diagnosis in production where no debugging is possible
> - help educate new developers in learning the application.

Comment: Should we always use XLogger instead of Logger.  - "Liberal use of these methods is encouraged ..."